# How to permanently/force delete a mysql database on rds/aurora

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a database I need to delete. I would like to keep the same endpoint and so I thought it would be as simple as doing:

```
drop database mydb;
create database mydb;
```

And everything would be fine. However, it's been a day since I did the `drop database` and it still has not worked. In fact, it seems like it has only resulted in creating a phantom database -- one that shows up in `SHOW DATABASES` but then when I click it or do `USE` it says:

> Unable to select database mydb. Please check you have the necessary
>   privileges to view the database and that it still exists.

I am logged in as the root user, so I should have the privileges.

Is there a fool-proof way to delete a database in rds/aurora? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: This should not be the behaviour. Could you please show the output of your console operations while trying to drop the database? Also, does it work if you pick a different database, so you can `CREATE DATABASE foo` then create a table in `foo`, then `DROP DATABASE foo`? This will highlight whether the problem lies with your particular database.

Comment: To my eye, that's a nonsensical garbage error message that is coming from whatever database browser tool you are using, and not from the actual Aurora cluster.  You might want see if your tool has a way to let you see the real error rather than somethong its developers incorrectly imagined would be helpful... or test with the `mysql` CLI to find the real error code and message.